# My Office Word Web Add-In does not start anymore. What should I do?

Tags: office-addins, word-addins

I bootstrapped this Word Add-In using yeoman generator quite a while ago.

When I type `npm start` it used to open a new command line with some debug information, start Word, and start Add-In in it.

Now when I type npm start it just says:

```
> office-addin-taskpane-react@0.0.1 start
> office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml

Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in 05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac64854143. Debug method: 0
Debugging started.
```

But nothing happens, no new console, no starting of word. And when I open the word, add-in is not there.

What was changed? Well I upgraded npm from 6.5 something to 7.10. That is all I can think of.

Since there is no error, I am a little stuck here. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I downgraded npm to 6.xx and it works now.